# Exponential distribution wait time probability

Tags: probability, exponential-function

I would like to check my answer, I have been asked to work out the probability of value greater then 10 given an exponential distribution with a mean of 10.

My intuition would be that this is equal to 0.5 but when I go to do a definite integral between 10 and infinity I get a decimal answer so small I would round it to zero.

What is the correct answer and what are the steps. Sorry if this is too simple.

Comment: Your intuition confuses the *mean* and the *median*. Let me suggest to check these terms.

Comment: Of course! That makes sense. So would the answer to the question then have a really low probability such as the one I worked out?

Comment: No - it is not $\frac12$ but nor is it close to $0$.  Show us your integral by editing your question (my guess is that you may have used a mean of $\frac1{10}$ rather than $10$, i.e. a rate of $10$ rather than a rate of $\frac1{10}$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the pdf be $p(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$.

Mean, $\mu=1/\lambda =10$.

$$P(X>10)=\int_\mu^\infty p(x)dx
=\int_{1/\lambda}^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx
=\left[\frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda x}}{-\lambda}\right]_{1/\lambda}^\infty=\frac 1e\qquad\blacksquare$$

Note that the answer is independent of $\mu$.

Comment: How wonderful! Now you can just turn in a screenshot and not have to think at all.

Comment: Some choose to post partial answers/guide steps, others choose to post complete answers. This is what makes MSE interesting.  It should up to the OP how he wants to use these responses.

Comment: I get your point @bruce, but a full solution does actually help me understand.

Comment: @Tom - Thanks. Glad you found that helpful.

Comment: @Tom How? Please be specific.

Answer (score 3):

I hate parameters and always try to get rid of them.

Let $Y$ have exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda=1$. Then $1$ is its mean and:

$$P(Y>1)=\int_1^\infty e^{-y}dy=\left[-e^{-y}\right]_1^\infty=e^{-1}$$

Now realize that $X:=10Y$ has exponential distribution with mean $\lambda=10$ and: $$P(X>10)=P(Y>1)=e^{-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $X \sim Exp(\mu = 10),$ then $P(X > 10) = e^{-1} =  0.3678794.$
Compare with the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of this distribution for details.

This should also be $\int_{10}^\infty f(x)\,dx,$ where $f(x)$ is the
density function of $X$. Are you sure you are integrating the
correct density function? Some books write the density function
in terms of the rate $\lambda = 1/\mu.$

If you wanted $P(X > \eta) = 0.5,$ then take logs to find $\eta = 6.931472.$
In this case $\eta$ is the median of $X.$

Comment: I started answering before the Comment of @Henry was posted. My second paragraph addresses the same issue. I agree with him that your confusion may be between _mean_ and _rate,_ rather than between _mean_ and _median._